# como llegar a SPAN para afectarlo CSS

Tags: html, css, css3

Como puedo llegar al span dentro del div para poder aplicarle CSS ya intente ">" y "child" que mas puedo hacer?

```css
div.br_alabel.br_alabel_type_text.berocket_alabel_id_10.br_alabel_better_compatibility>span:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/CnEbsTMBFFAMnycFdayoVsX7d14naKkMnoOx4pIrg-ppaF-zXNdkBcOnQEgDibsye-iy1V-Sf0d7SbWBSvMU0BXoPKQJ31Zdgk9y-eATFv5XB5GafkPFvg9LXNnEoORmyL9C") !important;
  font-size: 0;
  border: 0px;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  background-size: 100% 50% !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  padding: 40px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="br_alabel br_alabel_type_text berocket_alabel_id_10  br_alabel_better_compatibility" style="top:0px;right:0px;z-index:500;"><span style="height: 50px;width: 50px;background-color:#f16543;color:#ffffff;border-radius:50%;line-height:50px;font-size:14px;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;margin: -10px -10px 0px 0px;">
```

Comment: considera publicar el html de tu codig.

Comment: Estoy tratando de cambiar un css en una pagina de wordpress

Comment: dale en f12 para ver el códio de tu web y así nos puedas compartir el HTML, recuerda siempre poner un [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta con añadir un selctor inequívoco, como por ejemplo

```
div.br_alabel > span
```

Donde

elemento > hijo_inmediato

Adicionalmente no olvides que siempre el estilo embebido en las etiquetas tiene mayor precedencia.

```css
div.br_alabel.br_alabel_type_text.berocket_alabel_id_10.br_alabel_better_compatibility>span:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/CnEbsTMBFFAMnycFdayoVsX7d14naKkMnoOx4pIrg-ppaF-zXNdkBcOnQEgDibsye-iy1V-Sf0d7SbWBSvMU0BXoPKQJ31Zdgk9y-eATFv5XB5GafkPFvg9LXNnEoORmyL9C") !important;
  font-size: 0;
  border: 0px;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  background-size: 100% 50% !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  padding: 40px !important;
}

div.br_alabel > span{
 border: 1px dashed goldenrod !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="br_alabel br_alabel_type_text berocket_alabel_id_10  br_alabel_better_compatibility" style="top:0px;right:0px;z-index:500;">
  <span style="height: 50px;width: 50px;background-color:#f16543;color:#ffffff;border-radius:50%;line-height:50px;font-size:14px;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;margin: -10px -10px 0px 0px;">miSpan</span>
</div>
```